# Как получить данные поля POST для регистрации клиента после обработки формы заказа?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, form

Есть магазин на `woocommerce`.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при заказе товара шла проверка поля названия компании и если она новая, то создавался новый пользователь с ролью клиент, причем автоматически без регистраций и входа на сайт.

Саму функцию проверки нужного поля и создания пользователя я написал, остается только получить значение полей формы для проверки и во с этим у меня проблема.

Пробую сделать проверку подключившись к хуку woocommerce_thankyou, но поле формы отловить не получается **$_POST["billing_name"]**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_customer' );
function create_customer() {
   $customers = get_users( array( 'role' => 'customer' ) );
   foreach( $customers as $customer ) :
     $my_customer = get_user_meta( $customer->ID, 'billing_company', true );
     if($my_customer!=$_POST["billing_company"]) {
        $userdata = array(
        'user_pass'       => '123',
        'user_login'      => $_POST["billing_name"],
        'user_email'      => $_POST["billing_email"],
        'user_company'      => $_POST["billing_company"],
        'role'            => 'customer',
      );
      wp_insert_user( $userdata );
     }
   endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: `$post = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал подключившись к данным после самого заказа

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_user_callback' );
function create_user_callback($order_id){
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $order_detail['customer_first_name'] = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_first_name', true );
   $order_detail['customer_phone']      = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_phone', true );
   $order_detail['customer_email']      = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', true );
   $order_detail['customer_address']    = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_2', true );
   $customers = get_users( array( 'role' => 'customer' ) );
   foreach( $customers as $customer ) :
       $customers_email = get_user_meta( $customer->ID, 'billing_phone', true );
       if($customers_phone!=$order_detail['customer_phone'] && $customer->user_email!=$order_detail['billing_email']) {
            $userdata = array(
                'user_pass'          => '123',
                'user_login'         => $order_detail['customer_email'],
                'first_name'         => $order_detail['customer_first_name'],
                'user_email'         => $order_detail['customer_email'],
                'role'               => 'customer',
            );
            $userid = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( !is_wp_error( $userid ) ) { 
                add_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_phone', $order_detail['customer_phone'] );
                add_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_address_2', $order_detail['customer_address'] );
            }
       }
   endforeach;
}
```